# Simple HTML5 audio player works in firefox and safari, but not chrome: using mp3 and ogg. Need solution or fallback

Tags: html, browser, html5-audio, fallback

So here's a fiddle of what I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/bridget_kilgallon/rX6uD/1/

The song should play automatically on page load, and can be paused or played using the buttons. In firefox it all works. In safari the song won't autoplay on the working site, but it will autoplay in the fiddle and the buttons work in both instances. In chrome none of it works.

If anyone knows of a solution or a fallback that would be awesome.

```
<audio id="music" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="http://www.onlinebusinesscompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/03-Bump-City.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="http://www.onlinebusinesscompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/03_Bump_City.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

<button id="pausebtn" onclick="document.getElementById('music').pause()">Pause</button>
<button id="playbtn" onclick="document.getElementById('music').play()">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly for me in chrome, and a fallback is quite easily made:

```
<audio>
<source src="foo.com/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<p>This is a fallback<p>
<audio>
```

Cheers!